# Qt compatibility with GTK themes (Qbittorrent)?

Tags: themes, gtk, qt, qbittorrent

How can I make my Qbittorrent look somewhat more like my GTK theme or
just normal without switching/changing my current theme?

As usual I tried something and this came out:

---

How it looks without changes:
[image]

How it looks when I save settings with "Qt settings 4" while having Qbittorrent open:
[image]
Looks much better   |:3

The problem is when I close and open it again it looks like there the settings didn't save.
(It looked like the first image)

---

I have no idea if I'm misunderstanding some stuff here but this what I can make out of it.
Thanks for reading, any help kind of help would be quite nice.

Answer (score 3):

Try installing qt4-qtconfig:

```
sudo apt-get install qt4-qtconfig
```

Then run it by typing:

```
qtconfig-qt4
```

Click on the "Appearance" tab.

Choose GTK+ in the "GUI Style" dropdown.

Choose "File -> Save".

Profit

**Explanation:** The GTK+ style uses the GTK+ engine to render all qt components.

Answer (score 1):

The above method works for older versions of qbittorrent, but it doesn't work in newer versions because qbittorrent now uses qt5 instead of qt4.

So, if you are using a newer version of qbittorrent with qt5 you will need to install "libqt5libqgtk2" witch is a qt5/gtk2 platform theme library.
You can do that by typing this command in terminal,

```
apt install libqt5libqgtk2
```

Tested with Ubuntu-Gnome 16.04.2 LTS.

Comment: thanks, this worked for me too :) somehow this is not so much needed in xubuntu 16.04, and this package is not installed by default, I wonder how that works - qbittorrent looks ok right after installation, maybe except icons..

Answer (score 1):

Current qBittorrent 4.x is using Qt5 and libqt5libqgtk2 is not available for Ubuntu 20.

I was able to enable dark mode on Ubuntu 20 using "Kvantum Manager" available through Ubuntu Software:

- Install Kvantum Manager
- Open terminal and enter `echo "export QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=kvantum" >> ~/.profile`
- Restart
- Open Kvantum Manager and set the desired theme